# PHP - Get chunks of CSV by header name

Tags: php, arrays

I've got some different CSV files which contain blocks of inputs separated by WR

I want to make four separate arrays with with the data.

Eg.

```
Datum;Uhrzeit;WR;Status;SolIrr;TmpMod;TmpAmb;Wind;DaySumIrr;WR;Pac;DaySum;Status;Pdc1;Pdc2;Pdc3;Udc1;Udc2;Udc3;Temp;Uac;WR;Pac;DaySum;Status;Pdc1;Pdc2;Pdc3;Udc1;Udc2;Udc3;Temp;Uac;WR;Pac;DaySum;Status;Pdc1;Pdc2;Pdc3;Udc1;Udc2;Udc3;Temp;Uac
```

Would be come four arrays.

```
WR;Status;SolIrr;TmpMod;TmpAmb;Wind;DaySumIrr;
WR;Pac;DaySum;Status;Pdc1;Pdc2;Pdc3;Udc1;Udc2;Udc3;Temp;Uac;
WR;Pac;DaySum;Status;Pdc1;Pdc2;Pdc3;Udc1;Udc2;Udc3;Temp;Uac;
WR;Pac;DaySum;Status;Pdc1;Pdc2;Pdc3;Udc1;Udc2;Udc3;Temp;Uac;
```

The four arrays would then be inserted into four different MySQL tables.

I've managed to correctly split the headings into four arrays however I do not know how to then split each line of the data in the csv into separate arrays.

I hope I've made sense.

Thanks

Comment: What is the corresponding value under the WR column in your data rows? Is it blank or also WR?

Comment: I should also add, the WR blocks appear in different orders.

Comment: But for each CSV file, even if they appear in different orders, it will be consistent throughout the file? Like 5 Data Items, then WR, then 6 items then WR. and all data rows will follow that order?

Comment: Yes, it is consistent for the each file, however files have different orders.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you need, you can just use the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) method from php to split your strings from the csv file into an array. Using ; as delimiter :)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use built in `explode` function like this:

```
<?php

$string = 'WR;Status;SolIrr;TmpMod;TmpAmb;Wind;DaySumIrr;
WR;Pac;DaySum;Status;Pdc1;Pdc2;Pdc3;Udc1;Udc2;Udc3;Temp;Uac;
WR;Pac;DaySum;Status;Pdc1;Pdc2;Pdc3;Udc1;Udc2;Udc3;Temp;Uac;
WR;Pac;DaySum;Status;Pdc1;Pdc2;Pdc3;Udc1;Udc2;Udc3;Temp;Uac;';

# convert into lines
$lines = explode( PHP_EOL, $string );

# convert into items
$items = array();
foreach ( $lines as $line ) {
    $items[] = explode( ';', $line );
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by `exploding` the array

```
$filename=explode(";",$string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understand from your question, this is the solution I came up with.
First, get how the WR are ordered based on the headers, then generate an offset-length key-value pair. Use that key-value pair to slice the arrays of data which was exploded from each csv row.

```
<?php

  $headers = "Datum;Uhrzeit;WR;Status;SolIrr;TmpMod;TmpAmb;Wind;DaySumIrr;WR;Pac;DaySum;Status;Pdc1;Pdc2;Pdc3;Udc1;Udc2;Udc3;Temp;Uac;WR;Pac;DaySum;Status;Pdc1;Pdc2;Pdc3;Udc1;Udc2;Udc3;Temp;Uac;WR;Pac;DaySum;Status;Pdc1;Pdc2;Pdc3;Udc1;Udc2;Udc3;Temp;Uac";
  $headers_arr = explode(";", $headers);

  // track where WR is positioned in the array
  $WR_offset = array();
  foreach ($headers_arr as $i => $value) {
    if ($value == "WR") { $WR_offset[] = $i; }
  }
  $WR_offset[] = count($headers_arr); // assume imaginary WR as last header

  // loop through the WR_offset array,
  // to get the WR position, and the number of fields before the next WR position
  // to be used in array_slice
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($WR_offset) - 1; $i++) {
    $offset = $WR_offset[$i] + 1; // 
    $length = $WR_offset[$i+1] - $WR_offset[$i] - 1;
    // store the offset and length as key-value pair
    $slice_params[$offset] = $length;
  }

  // assuming $lines contains the CSV data rows, and $line is a single CSV data row
  foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $row_array = explode(";", $line);
    // loop through the generated offset-length value pair
    foreach ($slice_params as $offset => $length) {
      $array_chunks = array_slice($row_array, $offset, $length);
      // do what you want to do with the chunk here
    }
  }

?>
```

Comment: That looks like it may be what I was after.

Comment: I will include it into script and report back.